# How to prove that two Latin squares $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal if and only if $P^{-1}Q$ is a Latin square?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, latin-square

The inspiration of my question comes from Henry B. Mann's 1942 paper *The Construction of Orthogonal Latin Squares*. **My goal** is to add rigor to Mann's explanation that two Latin squares $P = (P_1,P_2,...,P_m)$ and $Q = (Q_1,Q_2,...,Q_m)$ are orthogonal if and only if $P^{-1}Q = (P_1^{-1}Q_1,P_2^{-1}Q_2,...,P_m^{-1}Q_m)$ is a Latin square, which is as follows:

> $P_i^{-1}P_j$ is the transformation which transforms the $i$th row of $(P_1,P_2,...,P_m)$ into the $i$th row of $(Q_1,Q_2,...,Q_m)$. Since every pair of variables occurs exactly once if the second square is imposed upon the first, the square $(P_1^{-1}Q_1,P_2^{-1}Q_2,...,P_m^{-1}Q_m)$ contains for every $i$ and $k$ a permutation which transforms $x_i$ into $x_k$. But then it can not contain two permutations which transform $x_i$ into $x_k$. This argument can be reversed and it follows that $(P_1,P_2,...,P_m)$ and $(Q_1,Q_2,...,Q_m)$ are orthogonal if and only if $(P_1^{-1}Q_1,P_2^{-1}Q_2,...,P_m^{-1}Q_m)$ is a Latin square.

**My Questions:** What does Mann mean by "transformations"? I feel like this wording is slightly vague and it is unclear to me what this means from a technical viewpoint. Also, why is it that if we assume $P^{-1}Q$ is not a Latin square, then this implies that $P^{-1}Q$ contains two permutations which transform $x_i$ into $x_k$?

If anyone knows of a more rigorous proof than the one Mann provided, that would answer all of my questions. Thanks for reading and for any responses!

*Mann, Henry B.*, [**The construction of orthogonal Latin squares**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177731539), Ann. Math. Stat. 13, 418-423 (1942). [ZBL0060.02706](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0060.02706).